# Error when installing Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity 5.3.1f1

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, installation, visual-studio-2015, unity-game-engine

I have both Unity 5.3.1f1 and Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Community edition properly installed and running (I've been using them separately for a while now). However, now that I try to install Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity, the installation process crashes giving me the following error:

> "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity Setup Wizard ended
>   prematurely because of an error. Your system has not been modified. To
>   install this program at a later time, run Setup Wizard again. Click
>   the Finish button to exit the Setup Wizard".

Of course, I already restarted my computer. I even uninstalled Visual Studio and Unity and then installed them again (that is really painful by the way). Nothing changes.

Can anyone help me on? I don't even know how to get support for something on the boundary like the Visual Studio Tools for Unity.

Here is a screen capture of the error:

[image: screen capture]

Answer (score 0):

From unity 5.2 and up i guess you don't need Visual Studio Tools for Unity as Unity from version 5.2 has native support for Visual Studio (same applies on 5.3.1f1).

i use Unity and visual studio with the tools

a link that can be helpful on what i said:

Native support for VSTU 2.1 in Unity 5.2
http://unityvs.com/documentation/native-support/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think so. I've read that before, but note that it says that you don't need to "import the VSTU Unity package anymore with Unity 5.2. Unity will detect if it's installed". But you still need to install the VSTU itself. That is what it is said at the very first line: "Starting with Unity 5.2, the Visual Studio Tools for Unity integrate natively inside Unity, which requires VSTU 2.1" and also in the checklist at the end: "Install Visual Studio and the Visual Studio Tools for Unity 2.1".